# RSpec instance double expectations and default parameter values

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to create a unit test for a class that has a dependency on an object I've created, `WebClient`, that makes authenticated web requests. I have created an `instance_double` of `WebClient` that I'm passing into the object and am going through mocking out its one public method, `make_json_request`, with a few sets of `with` expectations so it can return some hashes that I can use in my unit tests.

In the first method I'm testing, the method is called like so:

```
@web_client.make_json_request '/api/v1/endpoint', query: { territory: territory_id, status: 'active' }
```

And I'm setting up my `instance_double` like so:

```
web_client = instance_double('WebClient')

expect(web_client).to receive(:make_json_request)
   .with('/api/v1/endpoint', query: { territory: territory_id, status: 'active' })
   .and_return nil
```

When I attempt to run the tests in rspec, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: state = client.current_state
 #<InstanceDouble(WebClient) (anonymous)> received :make_json_request with unexpected arguments
   expected: ("/api/v1/endpoint", {:query=>{:territory=>1, :status=>"active"}})
        got: ("/api/v1/endpoint", {:query=>{}})
 Diff:
 @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 -["/api/v1/endpoint", {:query=>{:territory=>1, :status=>"active"}}]
 +["/api/v1/endpoint", {:query=>{}}]
```

It seems like it's receiving the message with the default values defined in the method signature, for some reason (method signature below):

```
def make_json_request(path, method: :get, body: {}, query: {})
```

I know for a fact that it's failing the expectation on the line that is actually passing the named parameter in with the appropriate values, and I'm at a loss of how to work around this. In other cases where I'm using a double, I have not had this problem - it's only in this one case, with named parameters with default values. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I was asked for the full code of the method that is being tested:

```
def load_entities(territory_id)
    path = '/api/v1/endpoint'
    @web_client.make_json_request path, query: { territory: territory_id, status: 'active' }
    .select { |d| d['status'] == 'active' }
end
```

**Edit 2**: The full spec:

```
describe Loader do
  let(:territory_id) { 1 }
  let(:web_client) {
    web_client = instance_double('WebClient')

    expect(web_client).to receive(:make_json_request)
      .with('/api/v1/endpoint', query: { territory: territory_id, status: 'active' })
      .and_return nil

    web_client
  }

  describe '.current_state' do
    it 'returns a State' do
      client = Loader.new territory_id, web_client: web_client

      state = client.current_state

      expect(state).to be_a State
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a full code of the method under test please?

Comment: i will do that right now.

Comment: Thanks, now please provide full spec's `it` block and its parent `describe` block's `before/after` callbacks as well :) Seems like you are not using instance_double correctly.

Comment: The last thing: where does you controller get `@web_client` instance variable from?

Comment: I pass in the instance double in the constructor. Otherwise the value is defaulted in the method argument.

Comment: The mistery resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case closed! Culprit: syntax error.

Change this:

```
@web_client.make_json_request path, query: { territory: territory_id, status: 'active' }
.select { |d| d['status'] == 'active' }
```

Into this:

```
@web_client.make_json_request(path, query: { territory: territory_id, status: 'active' }).select { |d| d['status'] == 'active' }
```

Because you are doing `#select` on `query` object, instead of doing in on `make_json_request`'s result. And it selects nothing from your `query`, as the spec shows.

Comment: Thank you SO much! This was driving me nuts. I'm not new to programming, but new to Ruby, and the optional parens are killing me lately. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I have years of experience with Ruby, and honestly not once did I use optional parens or named arguments. Well, it's either you who will become more conservative over time/experience with Ruby, or me who will need to start following fancy trends :) You are welcome!